# Event for checkbox value changed in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, datagridview

I have allready tried the CellValueChanged event, but this is only hitting when the cell is exited.. Is there an event that is instantly hitting when the checkbox is checked just like you have got one with the standalone checkboxes?

Comment: have you tried the grids `CellContentClick` event?

Answer (score 0):

you can use checked box in grid view with all kinds of data.if the the record has a valid value it is true or dose not have a valid value it is false . you answer is here
also you can fetch data with a Repeat loop (for or for-each) for finding you data and change it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
if (Grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != something)
{ to this; to that; change it;
}
}
```